# C# with datagridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a database with MySQL which is connected with C# windows application.
My problem is that I have a form with 2 buttons and datagridview. The one button is `exit` and the other is `clear`.
With the button `clear` I want to clear all the data in the database and I can’t do this.
The only thing I have done is to clear the entries and then when I reopen the entities are there!

THE CODE IS:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ //clear balance
    projectpizzaDataSet ds = new projectpizzaDataSet();
    projectpizzaDataSetTableAdapters.balanceTableAdapter daCust = new projectpizzaDataSetTableAdapters.balanceTableAdapter();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i); //delete error 
    }
}
```

Comment: With this code you are deleting rows from the DataGridView not from database.

Comment: It seems your question should be, "How to remove records from a database?" Other than refreshing the grid after deletion, the real problem has nothing to do with that control.

Comment: Can you post the code for how you are binding your data to the DataGridView?

Comment: string y = comboBox2.Text;
int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
double p = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);
daCust.Insert(x, y, p);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all but the solution is:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //clear balance
    projectpizzaDataSet ds = new projectpizzaDataSet();
    projectpizzaDataSetTableAdapters.balanceTableAdapter daCust = new projectpizzaDataSetTableAdapters.balanceTableAdapter();

    while (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 {
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    this.balanceTableAdapter.Update(projectpizzaDataSet.balance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete records from the database, you need to use the DELETE query. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189835.aspx) you can find how to use the DELETE command.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [Delete the rows from the DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/feh3ed13%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and then to [Update the TableAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233819%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables["TableName"].Rows)
    {
        row.Delete();
    }

    daCust.Update(ds);
}
```

Comment: i try the code but is not working. on the "tablename" i wrote "balance"

Comment: Check the links I posted and also this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233823.aspx). I'm sure you will find your answer. Maybe your tableAdatper has a delete method itself. Also post the code on how do you create your dataset